# Mounting a host file to container in docker python

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I am looking to map a command that runs in docker to docker python. Can someone help me with the same?

```bash
sudo docker run \
  -v /home/config/host_config.xml:/opt/confd/etc/confd/init/host_init.xml \
  --rm \
  -it \
  --privileged \
  --name container1 \
  host_config
```

I tried mapping with volumes option in container as follows:

```py
container = client.api.create_container(
  'host_config',
  'ls',
  name='container1',
  volumes=['/home/config/host_config.xml'],
  host_config=client.api.create_host_config(
    binds=['/home/config/host_config.xml:/opt/confd/etc/confd/init/host_init.xml']))
```

But I see the container creating is successful without any error but when I list using docker ps -a, it shows status as Exited.

Comment: Is `ls` the command to run in the container?  That will run instead of the image's `CMD`, and would cause the container to exit immediately.  Deleting that parameter might help.

Comment: What is your question? What behaviour would you expect instead? Please also make sure people here can reproduce this, we don't have the `host_config` image, for example. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].